# How do I create a banded matrix using values from a given function

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I would like to create a  matrix were values of the function P make up the diagonals. I tried using the For loop but did not get it right.

```
\[Alpha] = 0.6; 
n = 4; 
\[CapitalDelta]t = 1/n;
P[i_] := \[CapitalDelta]t^\[Alpha] (-1)^i Gamma[1 - \[Alpha]]/(
   Gamma[1 + i] Gamma[1 - \[Alpha] - i]); 
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> P[0], Band[{2, 1}] -> P[1]}, {n, 
   n}] // MatrixForm (* two bands on a matrix*)
```

Comment: your code seems to successfully produce a matrix with two bands...can you explain what should be different about it?

Comment: You can fill the entire matrix with `SparseArray[{i_, j_} -> P[i - j], {n, n}]` if that's what you need.

Comment: @thorimur I think the goal is to populate the diagonals which the exhibited expression does not do.

Comment: @WReach but which diagonals and how? "the diagonals" of a matrix is vague; it could mean the bands, or the way you've interpreted in your answer. And then the other question is "which values of `P`"—should there be a different value in each diagonal, or should the values vary within a single diagonal?

Comment: It is up to the OP to clarify intent. This question is phrased in a vague manner.

Answer (score 5):

We can repeat the value `P[1]` across the antidiagonal by changing the second `Band` expression as follows:

```
SparseArray[
  { Band[{1, 1}] -> P[0]
  , Band[{1, n}, Automatic, {1, -1}] -> P[1]
  }
, {n, n}
] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

The meaning of the second specification is as follows:

```
Band[
  {1, n}    /* start in row 1, column n */
, Automatic /* stop at an edge of the matrix */
, {1, -1}   /* each step advancing 1 row (down) and -1 column (left) */
]
```